# (Shiny, R) Making histogram from csv file (with column selection via combobox/Select input.

Tags: r, plot, shiny, histogram

I have another problem with my aplication. I need to add histogram function to it.

On third tab application should create histogram from uploaded file (column is selected via combobox/selectinput).

Application can actually create combobox with columns from csv file.

But when i want to make histogram, on tab "Histogram only displays error:

```
ERROR: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

I dont know what i made wrong.

There is code

```
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Aplikacja testowa nr 6. Praca z plikiem- wybór kolumny"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file", label = h3("Wgraj Plik")),
      checkboxInput(inputId = 'header', label = 'Pierwszy wers to etykiety', value = FALSE),
      radioButtons(inputId = 'sep', label = 'Co jest separatorem', choices = c("Przecinek"=',',"Średnik"=';',"Tabulator"='\t', "Spacja"=''), selected = ','),

      checkboxGroupInput("choices1", label = h3("Wybierz Kolumny"), choices = NULL),
      # there is combobox to pick column
        selectInput("combobox", label = h3("(Histogram) Wybierz kolumne"),  choices = NULL)





    ),

    mainPanel(
       uiOutput("tb")
    )
  )
))

server <- function(input, output, session){

  data <- reactive({
    file1 <- input$file
    if(is.null(file1)){return()} 
    dataSet <- read.csv(file=file1$datapath, sep=input$sep, header = input$header )

    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "choices1", choices = colnames(dataSet))
      # this line updates selection in combobox 
    updateSelectInput(session, "combobox", choices = colnames(dataSet))

    dataSet
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return ()}
    data()    
  })

  output$table2 <- renderTable({


    if(is.null(data()) || is.null(input$choices1)){return ()}
    data()[input$choices1]    
  })

# there is part of file where i make histogram
 output$wykres <- renderPlot({
x    <- data[0, input$combobox] 
 hist(x , col = 'blue', border = 'white')
})


  output$tb <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(data()))
      h5("Wgraj Plik jeśli chcesz cokolwiek zrobić.")
    else
      tabsetPanel(tabPanel("dane", tableOutput("table")),tabPanel("wybrane kolumny", tableOutput("table2")), tabPanel("Histogram", plotOutput("wykres")))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Inside the `hist` code, you forgot to put parenthesis after `data`. Should be `x <- data()[0, .......`

Comment: Oh...I'm sorry - I didn't see your comment before answering the question :(. By the way, there shouldn't be 0 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that you forgot add `()` to `data` in the following chunk of code.

```
output$wykres <- renderPlot({
    # x  <- data[, input$combobox] # zapomniales klamry 
    x    <- data()[, input$combobox] 
    hist(x , col = 'blue', border = 'white')
  })
```

I additionally expanded your code to avoid passing discrete variables into `hist` function by creating an alarm with `shinyBS` package and by adding `req(is.numeric(x))`.

```
library(shinyBS)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Aplikacja testowa nr 6. Praca z plikiem- wybór kolumny"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file", label = h3("Wgraj Plik")),
      checkboxInput(inputId = 'header', label = 'Pierwszy wers to etykiety', value = FALSE),
      radioButtons(inputId = 'sep', label = 'Co jest separatorem', choices = c("Przecinek"=',',"Średnik"=';',"Tabulator"='\t', "Spacja"=''), selected = ','),

      checkboxGroupInput("choices1", label = h3("Wybierz Kolumny"), choices = NULL),
      # there is combobox to pick column
      selectInput("combobox", label = h3("(Histogram) Wybierz kolumne"),  choices = NULL)

    ),

    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("tb")
    )
  )
))

server <- function(input, output, session){

  data <- reactive({
    file1 <- input$file
    if(is.null(file1)){return()} 
    dataSet <- read.csv(file=file1$datapath, sep=input$sep, header = input$header )

    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "choices1", choices = colnames(dataSet))
    # this line updates selection in combobox 
    updateSelectInput(session, "combobox", choices = colnames(dataSet))

    dataSet
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return ()}
    data()    
  })

  output$table2 <- renderTable({


    if(is.null(data()) || is.null(input$choices1)){return ()}
    data()[input$choices1]    
  })

  # there is part of file where i make histogram
  output$wykres <- renderPlot({
    x    <- data()[, input$combobox] 

    if (!is.numeric(x)) {
      createAlert(session, "alarm", alertId = "niebezpieczenstwo", 
                  title = "Niebezpieczenstwo: ",
                  content = "Histogram przyjmuje tylko wartosci ciagle!", 
                  style = "danger", dismiss = TRUE, append = TRUE)
    }
    if (is.numeric(x)) {
      closeAlert(session, "niebezpieczenstwo")
    }

    req(is.numeric(x))
    hist(x , col = 'blue', border = 'white')
  })


  output$tb <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(data()))
      h5("Wgraj Plik jeśli chcesz cokolwiek zrobić.")
    else
      tabsetPanel(tabPanel("dane", tableOutput("table")),
                  tabPanel("wybrane kolumny",
                            tableOutput("table2")), 
                  tabPanel("Histogram", 
                           bsAlert("alarm"),
                           plotOutput("wykres")))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you for your awnser. It really helped me.